# How to import a function to a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a single function to my Vue component. I've created a separated js file for my function:

randomId.js:

```
exports.randomId = () => //My function ...
```

In my Vue component, I've imported the Random js:

```
let randomId = require('../functions/randomId');
randomId();
```

but Webpack throws an error of "*randomId is not a function*".
I tried to import the file using import syntax, but the error remains.

```
import randomId from '../functions/randomId';
```

Should I use some other methods for importing single functions? I'm relatively new to Webpack and JS6.

Comment: You may find [this article helpful](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your function module to properly use ES6 export:

```
export function randomId() { /*My function ...*/ }
```

And then use ES6 named import:

```
import { randomId } from '../functions/randomId';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use CommonJS, then in the file with your randomId function do the following:

```
function randomId() {
   ...
}

module.exports = randomId;
```

And then the `let randomId = require('../functions/randomId');` in your Vue component will work.