# How should import be used in a single page Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have trouble importing an external class into a single file Vue component.

The component looks like this:

```
<style>
</style>
<template>
  <div>
    A page
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import AClass from './js/aclass.js';

// -----------------------------------------
// I have also tried all the below options
// -----------------------------------------

// import default from '/js/aclass.js';
// import * from '/js/aclass.js';
// import '/js/aclass.js';

// import default from '/js/aclass';
// import AClass from '/js/aclass';
// import * from '/js/aclass';

// import { AClass } from '/js/aclass.js';

// const AClass = require('/js/aclass.js');

module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        // console.log('ACLass', AClass);
    },
    destroyed: function(){
    },
    methods: {
    },
}
</script>
```

and the class file looks like this:

```
class AClass {
    constructor() {
        return this
    }
}

export AClass
```

or

```
export default class AClass {
    constructor() {
        return this
    }
}
```

None of the options seem to work: all the options based on `import` generate an error that says `ReferenceError: "responseText is not defined"` and the ones based on `require` one that says ÀClass is not defined` (when the console.log line is uncommented).

I have resorted to loading the class in the `window` global in the Vue.js base app - but everyone says that's barbaric, and I would like to be able to delay the loading of the library (the real one is heavier, and somewhat rarely used).

I have checked the various answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626259/vuejs-reactive-binding-to-module-export) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773478/how-to-import-a-function-to-a-vue-component) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611936/import-a-library-into-a-single-file-component-of-vue-js) but it looks like the mere use of `import` in the component makes things go wrong.

The component itself is loaded like this

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: (new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            { path: '/view/grid/:md5', component: httpVueLoader('components/view/grid.vue'), name: 'grid_md5' },  
        ] 
    })),
});
```

I am sure the solution must be there somewhere, but after about three hours of banging my head against this, I will throw myself at the mercy of the StackOverflow crowd.

Comment: Just to be sure of my understanding.... you problem is related to import an external script into your main html page, is it right? I'm confused because I saw `module.exports` and at same time `import ...` and not `require...`. Check it out this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: @FelipeJacob - my problem is importing a script in a Vue.js __component__ - exports and require are things I tried in desperation. However, the link you provide set me on the right path. Now I just gotta iron out a couple of details: (1) vue.js namespaces and (2) async vs sync loading (mostly an aesthetical issue). Thanks a lot. Would you want to provide an answer I can accept? Should I provide you with code on how I did it so that's easire?